# Setting Up Nginx as a Reverse Proxy Server doesn't work

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm trying to set up nginx as a reverse proxy for this simple node.js script

```
const http = require('http');
 
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;
 
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World!\n');
});
 
server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

but https://example.com/app doesn't work

Tried running it on 0.0.0.0 and it works on ip:port, sudo nginx -t is alright, restarted nginx but my location i set in the nginx config isn't accessible, it says error 404 not found on https://example.com/app this is the nginx config

```
server {
    location /app {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" needs more technical details. Check your access log and see how the request was handled.

Comment: When you test it on `localhost:3000`, does it work as `http://localhost:3000/` or `http://localhost:3000/app`? Because your Nginx reverse proxy is sending the latter.

Comment: it works on http://localhost:3000/

Comment: followed the instructions from here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-20-04 but still can't access it from https://example.com/app, 404 not found (nginx)